# Control Report Permission Based on Parameters in Reporting Services

Tags: security, reporting-services

Assume we have a report called SalesSummary for a large department. This department has many smaller teams for each product. People should be able to see information about their own product, not other teams' products. We also have one domain group for each of these teams.

Copying SalesSummary report for each team and setting the permission is not the best option since we have many products.  I was thinking to use a code similar to below on RS, but it doesn't work. Apparently, System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal is disabled by default on RS.

```
Public Function isPermitted() As Boolean
   Dim Principal As New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
   If (Principal.IsInRole("group_prod")) Then
      Return true
   Else
      Return false
   End If
End Function
```

I also thought I can send the userID from RS to SQL server, and inside my SP I can use a code similar to below to query active directory. This also doesn't work due to security restriction.

```
SELECT
* 
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'SELECT cn, ADsPath FROM ''LDAP://DC=Fabricam,DC=com'' WHERE objectCategory=''group''')
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this goal?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I got a similar situation, I was going to use a ReportViewer control and let my app control the remote access to the Report Server and pass in discrete parameters.

Comment: How does it work with exporting report? Does it export reports through ReportViewer or send the URL to RS. I don't want people to hack their way by building querystring or changing the post variables.

Comment: AFAIK the ReportViewer would do the export as well. User wouldn't even have access to the report server. I just need to make sure the discrete parameters are secure and can not be modified by user during the parameter prompting stage.

Comment: @dotjoe I think I am gonna try your approach. Could you please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option you suggested (using embedded code to identify the executing user) will not be reliable. SSRS code is not necessarily executed as the user accessing the report, and may not have access to that users credentials, such as when running a subscription.

Your second approach will work, but requires the appropriate permissions for your SQL server service account to query Active Directory.

Another approach is to maintain a copy of the group membership or user permissions in a SQL table. This table can be updated by hand or with an automated process. Then you can easily incorporate this into both available parameters and core data queries.

Comment: We are already keeping the user groups and their privilege in the database, but we don't want to keep the user name as well. It is really hard to maintain. The problem is to find out which groups a user belongs to. Thanks for your comment about SSRS not always running the code.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up with this code:

```
        PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "AD");
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, identityName);
        //// if found - grab its groups
        if (user != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> _groups = null;
            int tries = 0;
           //We have this while because GetGroups sometimes fails! Specially if you don't
           // mention the domain in PrincipalContext
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    _groups = user.GetGroups();
                    break;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Debug("get groups failed", ex);
                    if (tries > 5) throw;
                    tries++;
                }
            }

            // iterate over all groups, just gets groups related to this app
            foreach (Principal p in _groups)
            {
                // make sure to add only group principals
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    if (p.Name.StartsWith(GROUP_IDENTIFIER))
                    {
                        this.groups.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                        this.groupNames.Add(p.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

Now, that you have a list of related group you can check the list to authorize the user!